# WPF UI won't update even though I am using a dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main thread and a child thread. The child thread is sta and updates the ui. The main thread does calculations. I am using the following code in the sta thread:

```
m.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    m.ProgressText.Content = newPrText;
    m.ProgressBar.Value += prInc;
    m.ProgressBar.Maximum = prMax;
});
```

The UI just freezes and hangs. It does not update the fields.

Answer (score 4):

You should switch it around: Let the main thread update the UI and the child thread perform the calculations. Most likely, the controls are created on the main thread, so the dispatcher will marshal the updates back to the main thread, effectively performing all work on the main thread.

Comment: In that case you need to show more details. But did you create the whole UI on the child thread or only part? Still, I don't know why you would want it that way. Why not go the usual route?

Comment: I created the whole UI on the child thread. I am going to try the other way around and see how that works.

Comment: Never start up another sta thread and don't even think about creating controls on any thread other than the default one you get when you run your app.